# error in downloading graphics.h

Tags: command-line, sdl

I am trying to download graphics.h header file but after

1.`sudo apt-get install build-essential`, there is no upgrade  in my pc

2.download of `libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz` file.
3.`./configure` it not working but, error is given as:

```
configure: error: *** SDL version 1.2.0 not found!
```

Please help?

Answer (score 6):

### How to fix it

For that error, you need to install development files for version 1.2 of `libSDL` and `libSDL-image`:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev
```

It may also ask you for Guile, just install that one as well:

```
sudo apt-get install guile-1.8-dev
```

Then run `./configure` again.

### What was the problem

The software that you were trying to install, `libgraph`, has some dependencies. It uses other pieces of software and expects you to have them already installed. When you run `./configure`, you check that you have everything you need before proceeding with the next step (`make`).

The error you got said that you don't have the headers for `libSDL` that are needed to compile `libgraph`. Of course, you can get the `libSDL` sources from the Internet and install them. But those have dependencies of their own, and it would be a rather tedious process. Instead, you can just install them from Ubuntu's repositories.

### How to find out the required package name

```
apt-cache search libsdl | grep dev
```

### For Ubuntu 17.10 and above

Follow the same steps as above except that you will need to install guile using

```
sudo apt-get install guile-2.0-dev
```

as `guile-1.8` is no longer officially supported

Answer (score -1):

Source: http://www.codingalpha.com/install-run-graphics-h-ubuntu/

1. Download Libgraph v(libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz) to your USR directory in Linux Ubuntu.
2. Extract it in your USR Directory or the Home folder.
3. Now, you can do a #include and run your C programs

Comment: I'm pretty sure binary library files are necessary on top of the header files.