# How to change directories in Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash?

Tags: graphics, windows

How to change directories easily in Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash and where to place libgraph folder for using graphics?
I can't find that hidden folder suggested in some articles from different websites(lxss folder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use graphics.h in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

With command:

```
cd directory_path
```

You can view the content of the current directory by typing:

```
ls
```

To change to previous directory type:

```
cd ../
```

To view hidden files and folders type:

```
ls -a
```

Comment: This is a partial answer -- how to view hidden folders would be a helpful addition, at a minimum (where the libgraph folder is supposed to go may be resolved once the questioner can see the hidden stuff).