# trying to install libgraph

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I'm trying to install the libgraph library in Ubuntu 17.04. The `./configure` file was successful but when I said `make` it gives a error:

```
Makefile:934: warning: overriding recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Makefile:409: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2'
Makefile:934: warning: overriding recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Makefile:409: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
Making all in man
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc/man'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc/man'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2'
Makefile:934: warning: overriding recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Makefile:409: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
if /bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I.                 -g -O2 -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -DFONTDIR=\""/usr       /local/share/libgraph/Font/"\" -g -O2 -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1      -D_REENTRANT -MT guile-libgraph.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/guile-libgraph.Tpo"  -c -o guile-libgraph.lo guile-libgraph.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/guile-libgraph.Tpo" ".deps/guile-libgraph.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/guile-libgraph.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I. -g -O2 -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -DFONTDIR=\"/usr/local/share/libgraph/Font/\" -g -O2 -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -MT guile-libgraph.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/guile-libgraph.Tpo -c guile-libgraph.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/guile-libgraph.o
guile-libgraph.c:25:22: fatal error: libguile.h: No such file or directory
#include <libguile.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:460: recipe for target 'guile-libgraph.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [guile-libgraph.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2'
Makefile:552: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2'
Makefile:268: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`./configure` gives this output:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for g77... no
checking for f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for f90... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if gcc static flag  works... yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking for gawk... (cached) mawk
checking for sdl-config... /usr/bin/sdl-config
checking for SDL - version >= 1.2.0... yes
checking SDL  ==>  SDL_image library... SDL_image = yes
checking for Guile... yes
checking for rint in -lm... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking vfork.h usability... no
checking vfork.h presence... no
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for atexit... yes
checking for putenv... yes
checking for rint... yes
checking for strdup... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/man/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

Comment: You need to install the dependent package: `guile-2.0-dev`.

Comment: i have already install guile-2.0-dev

Comment: Can you post the output of `make V=1` in the question, this will put verbose output for the commands used to build the library.

Comment: after make is the main problem

Comment: Makefile:934: warning: overriding recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Makefile:409: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2'
Makefile:934: warning: overriding recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Makefile:409: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Making all in doc

Comment: make[2]: Entering directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
Making all in man
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc/man'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc/man'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/maverick/libgraph-1.0.2'

Comment: Can you edit the question  and post the results there as the formatting is completely lost in comments.

Comment: i am a beginner i am not aware of the formatting

Comment: You can click on this link to help you edit the question you have posted: [https://askubuntu.com/posts/942863/edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/942863/edit)

Comment: There are some prerequisites (updates and other packages). Check here for them : https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu/525052#525052

Answer (score 10):

libgraph expects `libguile.h` to be in the standard include paths which it is not. The autoconf script should really find the correct locations (which I consider a build system bug) but it doesn't, so you need to add its include path to the preprocessor and linker flags. The standard approach would be:

```sh
sudo apt install guile-2.0-dev  # In case you didn't install it earlier
CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS $(pkg-config --cflags-only-I guile-2.0)" \
  CFLAGS="$CFLAGS $(pkg-config --cflags-only-other guile-2.0)" \
  LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $(pkg-config --libs guile-2.0)" \
  ./configure
make
```

Alternatively you can build libgraph without Guile module support:

```sh
./configure --disable-guile
make
```

Comment: Hi, my version of Linux (Pop!OS 21.04) has only `guile-2.2-dev` and `guild-3.0-dev` available. And I already have the former one installed, Yet I face the error that `<libguile.h>` not found.
The method mentioned above worked for me. I just had to use `guile-2.2` in the flags instead

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you have basic compilers installed. For this run the command:

   `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
2. Install few packages that required. Run the command:

   `sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-1.8 guile-1.8-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev`
3. Now download libgraph.
   Copy libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz to your home folder. Right click on it and select "Extract Here".
   Then run following commands one by one.

   `cd libgraph-1.0.2`

   `./configure`

   `sudo make`

   `sudo make install`

   `sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libgraph.* /usr/lib`

Answer (score 0):

This is Tushar.
Please follow, the alternative method given by David Foerster. It works for me!

```
./configure --disable-guile

sudo make

sudo make install

sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libgraph.* /usr/lib
```

Answer (score -1):

The new libguile source is installed in /usr/include/guile/2.0/
so just doing

```
sudo mv /usr/include/guile/2.0/* /usr/include/
```

Will fix the compilation without changing all the #includes in libgraph.

Comment: Moving around files that are managed by the package manager is asking for trouble. It would be better to add `/usr/include/guile/2.0` to the compiler include path in this particular case. -1