# Error while using graphics.h

Tags: drivers, graphics, compiling, virtual-console

I have visited this [site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu)
to know how to use graphics.h

But I am getting an error while using

> sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-1.8 \
>     guile-1.8-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev \
>     libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev \
>     libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev \
>     libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev

I am getting an error like this:

```
koolman@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-1.8 guile-1.8-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev  
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done  
libaa1 is already the newest version (1.4p5-44build1).  
libasound2 is already the newest version (1.1.0-0ubuntu1).  
libfreetype6 is already the newest version (2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.3).  
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
 linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic  
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.  
The following additional packages will be installed:  
 autotools-dev esound-common guile-1.8-libs libaudiofile1 libcaca-dev libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdrm-dev libesd0 libgl1-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libjbig-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libltdl-dev liblzma-dev libncurses5-dev libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libpulse-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp libreadline6-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtiff5-dev libtiffxx5 libtinfo-dev libtool libwebp-dev libwebpdemux1 libx11-dev libx11-doc libx11-xcb-dev libxau-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb1-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxfixes-dev libxshmfence-dev libxxf86vm-dev mesa-common-dev pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev   
Suggested packages: guile-1.8-doc libasound2-doc pulseaudio-esound-compat libglib2.0-doc gmp-doc libgmp10-doc libmpfr-dev libtool-doc liblzma-doc ncurses-doc readline-doc autoconf automaken gfortran | fortran95-compiler gcj-jdk libxcb-doc libxext-doc pavumeter pavucontrol paman paprefs  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
 autotools-dev esound-common guile-1.8 guile-1.8-dev guile-1.8-libs libaa1-dev libart-2.0-dev libasound2-dev libaudiofile-dev libaudiofile1 libcaca-dev libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libdrm-dev libesd0 libesd0-dev libfreetype6-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libjbig-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libltdl-dev liblzma-dev libncurses5-dev libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libpulse-dev libreadline6-dev libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev libsdl1.2debian libslang2-dev libtiff5-dev libtiffxx5 libtinfo-dev libtool libwebp-dev libwebpdemux1 libx11-dev libx11-doc libx11-xcb-dev libxau-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb1-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxshmfence-dev libxxf86vm-dev mesa-common-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev  
The following packages will be upgraded:  
 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils  
7 upgraded, 81 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.  
Need to get 756 kB/15.9 MB of archives.  
After this operation, 75.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y  
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 x11proto-core-dev all 7.0.31-1~ubuntu16.04.1  
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mesa-common-dev amd64 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]  
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgl1-mesa-dev amd64 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 404 Not Found  
[IP: 91.189.91.23 80] Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 x11proto-core-dev all 7.0.31-1~ubuntu16.04.1 404 Not Found   
[IP: 91.189.91.23 80] E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/x11proto-core/x11proto-core-dev_7.0.31-1~ubuntu16.04.1_all.deb 404 Not Found  
[IP: 91.189.91.23 80] E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa-common-dev_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found  
[IP: 91.189.91.23 80] E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dev_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found   
[IP: 91.189.91.23 80] E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @MartinThornton yeah I have tried that

Comment: koolman@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update

Comment: No you didn't! Look more closely, there should be no `install`!