# How do I use graphics.h with libgraph in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: system-installation, package-management, 18.04, sdl

How do I use graphics.h in Ubuntu 18.04? I am getting the following error message when trying to follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu/525052#525052) to compile and install libgraph in order to use graphics.h on Ubuntu.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-1.8 \  
>   guile-1.8-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev \  
>   libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev \  
>   libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev \  
>   libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev  
[sudo] password for linux: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package guile-1.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'guile-1.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'guile-1.8'
E: Unable to locate package guile-1.8-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'guile-1.8-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'guile-1.8-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libesd0-dev
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What you are going to achieve? What software are you trying to compile? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1042859/edit) your question and answer these questions. Could you please insert text output instead of images?

Comment: @N0rbert I have edited the question in order to answer your questions, and  inserted text output instead of the screenshot image of the terminal output.

Answer (score 2):

Three of the packages in the command in your question that returned an error message have been updated in 18.04. In the "Install some additional packages" step in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu/525052#525052) open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-2.0 \
  guile-2.0-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev \
  pulseaudio-esound-compat libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev \
  libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev \
  libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev
```

To make it easier to copy/paste it in the terminal here is the previous command reformatted as a single line:

```
sudo apt install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-2.0 guile-2.0-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev pulseaudio-esound-compat libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev
```

Comment: http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/libgraph/libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz
i have tried to install this software link above but showing this error below ....
guile-libgraph.c:25:10: fatal error: libguile.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libguile.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: The libguile.h file is located at `/usr/include/guile/2.0/libguile.h` in Ubuntu 18.04 assuming that you installed guile-2.0-dev as the command said to do. Try adding a [symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link) to the libguile.h file to the libgraph-1.0.2 directory.