# Unable to locate package libesd0-dev on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, graphics, c

I used:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-2.0 \
guile-2.0-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev \
libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev \
libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev \
libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev
```

I got:

```
E: Unable to locate package libesd0-dev
```

I was following [How do I use graphics.h in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu) but it's not working.

I want to use `<graphic.h>` in Ubuntu for C programs.

Comment: @Kulfy I am a student and new to stack overflow and not familiar with ubuntu and any linux Os. Can you please tell me why it is not working in my pc? though i am copying from that link and even changed version of guile according to my system ?

Comment: @Kulfy Yes I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. can you please solve my problem acrrording to this version? Please provide me what to copy and paste in terminal to solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Ubuntu 18.04 `libesd0-dev` is deprecated. For this you need to add repositories of **xenial**, i.e. repository of a previous Ubuntu release which is still supported, in `sources.list`.

Open Terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

A list will be opened in nano. Copy and paste these two lines at the end:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe
```

Save and close using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libesd0-dev
```

Comment: Yes that solved the problem of libesd0_dev. But still their is some problem. guile-libgraph.c:25:10: fatal error: libguile.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libguile.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.