# Can we use graphics.h library for C/C++ on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: graphics, c++, c

For a few days now, I have trying to install the graphics.h library in 20.04 and failed and then tried on 18.04 and it worked and I can use it, but I really want to know if one could use graphics.h library on 20.04 as I want to continue my work on that and still have to use this particular library..?

Comment: What package you trying to install?  There are at least eight of them with a graphics.h include file.  How are trying to install it?

Comment: I am using this particular link to install the library but the dependencies required by it don't seem to work out in 20.04 and hence was wondering that would their be a way around it...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I did install (using a few tutorials) & Use graphics.h library in Ubuntu 20.04 (in a virtual machine) and it worked fine. Except for some "warning" messages displayed when I run my compiled apps...

Comment: Can you explain how you installed it? I think that's what the question is asking