# Error while installing graphics.h library on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: c++, 20.10, programming

please answer my question as i can't installing graphics.h library in ubuntu 20.10. It shwoing me erros as libs0-dev not found. showing while installing packages

Answer (score 0):

See [How do I use graphics.h in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu)  the libesd0-dev package was deprecated and is loaded differently.

Comment: error while adding resporitory