# How to install and use graphics.h in Ubuntu for c language?

Tags: graphics

I am using Ubuntu for the very first time and I want to install `graphics.h` library in it. How can I do that? I tried various things but as I am new to Ubuntu and linux I have no idea what to do? Also I can't use other libraries because our subject teacher told us not to !
It will be better if you provide a latest solution.

Comment: Have you searched for the package containing your `graphics.h`? https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use graphics.h in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu)